# Facebook Audience Network ios FBAdView width

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I added a FBAdView to a UIView in the view controller.
(I set the view background to red)
the FBAdView was created with adSize of kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner.
The problem is that the FBAdView calculates its width when it is being added, but after rotating the device it doesn't calculate its width again

I tried using autolayout but it didn't work

code for adding the FBAdview (Adding to UILabel with red backgroud)

`FBAdView *fbAdView = [[FBAdView alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"***************_***************"
                                   adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner
                       rootViewController:self];
    fbAdView.delegate = self;
    [fbAdView loadAd];
    [self.banner addSubview:fbAdView];`

code for autolayout - doesn't work

// Width constraint, parent view width
    [self.banner addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fbAdView                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                                      toItem:self.banner
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];

```
// Height constraint, parent view height
[self.banner addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fbAdView                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                                      toItem:self.banner
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];

// Center horizontally
[self.banner addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fbAdView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.banner
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

// Center vertically
[self.banner addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fbAdView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.banner
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

print screen
when the banner is added it fit the screen width
after rotating it doesn't change its width (like its parent red view)

[image: The banner after rotating]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing some constraints.

Adding these lines (might need some minor changes) makes your code work:

```
self.banner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
fbAdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


// Width constraint
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.banner
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                    multiplier:1
                                                      constant:0]];

// Height constraint
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[banner(==50)]"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(banner)]];
```

I've posted a sample project at https://github.com/overlordnyaldee/BannerAutoLayout

Comment: Thanks
the line "fbAdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;" is what I needed